# Why is the value NULL entered into my database when I use CASE for my SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

To prevent multiple SQL statements from being sent to the database like this:

```
UPDATE `gmw-db-051514`.`gmw_provider`
SET `gmw_provider`.`is_partner` = TRUE,
`partner_url` = 'some-url',
`partner_remove_token` = 'ABC123'
WHERE `gmw_provider`.`provider_id` = '11';

UPDATE `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations`
SET `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` = 30
WHERE `tbl_conversations`.`user_initial_id` = 30;

UPDATE `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations`
SET `tbl_conversations`.`partner_target_id` = 30
WHERE `tbl_conversations`.`user_following_id` = 30;
```

... I would like to merge these SQL statements into one.
I know that I can use IF and CASE in MYSQL statements but I think I'm using it wrong.

This is my attempt to use the CASE statement

```
UPDATE
  `gmw-db-051514`.`gmw_provider`,
  `gmw-db-051514`.`tbl_conversations`
SET
  `gmw_provider`.`is_partner` = true,
  `partner_url` = 'some-url',
  `partner_remove_token` = 'ABC123',
  `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` =
CASE WHEN 
  `tbl_conversations`.`user_initial_id` = '30' THEN '30' END,
  `tbl_conversations`.`partner_target_id` =
CASE WHEN 
  `tbl_conversations`.`user_following_id` = '30' THEN '30' END
WHERE
  `gmw_provider`.`provider_id` = '11'
```

The Condition works, but if there is already a value in a row, it is rewritten to null.

Have a look at this table:

```
 |user_initial_id|user_following_id|partner_initial_id|partner_target_id|
 |     30        |        41       |       NULL       |        41       |
 |     51        |        41       |       NULL       |        41       |
 |     37        |        30       |       NULL       |        NULL     |
```

After executing the UPDATE Statement it looks like this (41 is gone)

```
 |user_initial_id|user_following_id|partner_initial_id|partner_target_id|
 |     30        |        41       |       30         |        NULL     |
 |     51        |        41       |       NULL       |        NULL     |
 |     37        |        30       |       NULL       |        30       |
```

But it should look like this (41 still there and 30 added):

```
 |user_initial_id|user_following_id|partner_initial_id|partner_target_id|
 |     30        |        41       |       30         |        41       |
 |     51        |        41       |       NULL       |        41       |
 |     37        |        30       |       NULL       |        30       |
```

The row **user_initial_id** corresponds to **partner_initial_id**.

The row **user_following_id** corresponds to **partner_target_id**.

Like this:

```
        A                 B                 A                  B
 |user_initial_id|user_following_id|partner_initial_id|partner_target_id|
```

Can you help me out with this or another attempt?
The "IF" statement leads to the same result.

Of course I used google and found similar questions here on stackoverflow, but the examples were more simple and not in combination with another table. I was afraid that this could affect the exact solution for these conditions.

If you can't help me, I use the multi-query version but this looks very ugly to me.

Thanks!

EDIT: My problem was solved and I've learned something new! If someone looks 
for a similar solution consider:
1.) Using Joins
2.) Don't be afraid of "sending a few queries through the same connection" :-)

Thanks to @dognose and @gordon Linoff!

Comment: Why don't you use a SINGLE transaction to execute two statements, without having to worry about other statements happening at that time? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: ps.: If you just think, one statement will be faster than 3 statements, you are most likely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not quite understand you. Do you mean from PHP as a whole query? This is not possible, I have to send it as a multi-query then.

Comment: In PHP, `PDO` offers all the required functionality for transactional processing: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Hm. ok, I thought I could save some performance if I do not connect so often with the database but do the dirty work in mysql.

Comment: OK, I'm using mysqli

Comment: Yes, connecting is somewhat "expensive", but no one would judge you for sending 3 queries through the same connection, once established :-)

Comment: I understand what you mean! This is something I've learned now. Also to consider using explicit joins. Thank you I'll play around with both solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `else` clause for the `case`:

```
  `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` =
(CASE WHEN `tbl_conversations`.`user_initial_id` = '30' THEN '30' 
      ELSE `tbl_conversations`.`partner_initial_id` END)
```

I would also recommend table aliases and explicit `JOIN` conditions as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution works! I'm already using joins to iterate through multiple tables, then i decided to try this solution. I'll consider JOIN to find out a good practise here...

Comment: Hey, I asked an additional question here on stackoverflow but it is still unanswered. Maybe you can help me out again? How can I update the first(gmw_provider) of these two tables even if the second table(tbl_conversations) is empty? I can send you the URL to the original question if needed.

Comment: Btw. I considered using explicit JOIN in the meantime. But I can't find a reference point because the table has two of them: The user who starts a conversation (user_initial_id) and the user who receives the first message (user_following_id). These reference points differ from each conversation. But I'm on it :-)